# Change h:mm:ss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

i am working with python and i have a df as:

```
time
00:01:24
00:22:44
00:12:32
00:02:56
```

and i want to change it as

```
time
01:24:00
22:44:00
12:32:00
02:56:00
```

i first removed 00: from the column by using:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.strip('00:)
```

and then tried

```
df['time'] =pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%H:%M").dt.time
```

but is giving error as

```
ValueError: time data '1' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)
```

Eventually while striping 00:   the column values are becoming

```
1:24
22:44
12:32
2:56
```

Can someone help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%S:%H:%M").dt.time
df
```

**Output**

```
    time
0   01:24:00
1   22:44:00
2   12:32:00
3   02:56:00
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function of Pandas.

```
df['time'].str.replace(r"^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})",r"\2:\3:\1")
```

***Explanation:*** Working on DataFrame's `time` column and using `.str.replace` function to replace values. In matching portion using capturing group capability of function to create 3 capturing groups(where 1st one will have 1st 2 digits followed by colon, 2nd and 3rd one will also be same), then while substituting it interchanging their places to get the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Do a cast to [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime), change to required format.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%S:%H:%M").dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```